# using ~~ correctly

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse through a simple enough file of field and value pairs. 
So some fields I am not interested in and I want to skip

So in my "play" code I had a static thing like this: 
    next if $field =~ m/fieldToIgnore1|fieldToIgnore2/;

... then I extended this an an array and still happy

```
print "== using ~~ ==\n";
foreach my $field (@fields) {
  next if $field ~~ @foni;
  print "$field\n";
}
```

(fnoi == fields not of interest)

But when I carry that over back into my non-play setup it doesn't work. 
Now in the play I was just looping over

```
my @fields = ("field1", "field2");
my @foni = ("fieldToIgnore1", "fieldToIgnore1");
```

In my proper code I go through each line and take out the lines that are setup like field - value lines and then strip out the field into a scalar... hence why I thought it would the same idea as my play code - but it doesn't seem to be

```
while ( <$infile> ) {

  if ( /^PUBLISH:/ ) {

    ( $symbol, $record_type ) = ( $1, $2 );
    print "symbol is: [$symbol]\n"; 

  } else {
    my ( $field, $value ) = split(/\|/);
    next unless $value;

    print "field is: [$field]\n";
    print "value is: [$value]\n";

    $field =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    $value =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

    print "... field is: [$field]\n";
    print "... value is: [$value]\n";

    ## ADD FIELD SKIPPING LOGIC HERE
```

Comment: Note that `~~` is experimental in current Perl and its behaviour is subject to change. Also, without showing actual input, we can't run your code to test our solutions. Moreover, you're using `$1` and `$2`, but there are no parentheses anywhere.

Comment: Smart matching is very unlikely to be fixed, and will probably be removed from the language sooner or later. Don't use it. Take a look at [*Rethinking smart matching*](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/rethinking-smart-matching.html)

Comment: Note "( $symbol, $record_type ) = ( $1, $2 );" instruction in your code.
"$1" and "$2" refer to the content caught by respective capturing groups in last regex. But your last regex does not contain any capturing groups. What do you want to do here?

Comment: Ok... I'll not use it, as I read similar concerns elsewhere. Figured out a more standard approach - thanks anyhow  :D

Comment: Re "*using ~~ correctly*", The correct way to use `~~` is to not use it. It is an experimental features with design bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a regex pattern from your array, like this

```
my $re = join '|', @foni;
$re    = qr/$re/;                  # Compile the regex

for my $field (@fields) {
    next if $field =~ $re;
    ...
}
```